# Set Source for MenuItem in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, menuitem

I've a `Menu` with `MenuItem`s which are bound to `RegionType`enum.
MenuItems should have checkmarks and I want to bound `IsChecked` to some `ObservableCollection<bool>` (`VisibleRegions`):

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="enumData" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="target:RegionType"/>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

And Menu itself:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Choose item" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource enumData}}">
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding VisibleRegions, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

VS Output tells me in runtime:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'VisibleRegions' property not found on 'object' ''RegionType'
>   (HashCode=0)'. BindingExpression:Path=VisibleRegions;
>   DataItem='RegionType' (HashCode=0); target element is 'MenuItem'
>   (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Boolean')

The message is pretty clear but how do I correct this xaml piece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straightforward way in xaml to get the current index when binding to a collection.

So, what you should do is to bind to an `ObservableCollection` of a class that combines the enum values with the bool (`IsChecked`). For example:

```
public class EnumData
{
    public string Enum { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}


var enumData = new ObservableCollection<EnumData> (Enum.GetNames(typeof(YourEnum))
    .Select(s => new EnumData { Enum = s, IsChecked = false }));
```

And then just set the `DisplayMemberPath` to the property you want displayed:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Choose item" ItemsSource="{Binding enumData}" DisplayMemberPath="Enum">
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```